# How to get particular data from nested arrays using .map or flatmap in angular2/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have following json,

```
{   "damages": {        "regions": [{
                "name": "External Damages",
                "totalEstimatedCost": "$ 0.00",
                "damageDetails": [{
                    "areaDes": "FRONT Hood",
                    "type": "Prev Repair",
                    "desc": "Acceptable",
                    "estimate": "$ 0.00",
                    "isClickable": true,
                    "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
                    "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
                    "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
                }]          },          {
                "name": "Other Damages",
                "totalEstimatedCost": "$ 0.00",
                "damageDetails": [{
                        "areaDes": "FRONT Front Bumper Cover",
                        "type": "Prev Repair",
                        "desc": "Acceptable",
                        "estimate": "$ 0.00",
                        "isClickable": true,
                        "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
                        "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
                        "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "areaDes": "INT OPT Gas",
                        "type": "Empty",
                        "desc": "Unacceptable",
                        "estimate": "$ 0.00",
                        "isClickable": true,
                        "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
                        "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
                        "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "areaDes": "LF DR L \"A\" Pillar",
                        "type": "Prev Repair (Structure)",
                        "desc": "Substd Repair",
                        "estimate": "$ 0.00",
                        "isClickable": true,
                        "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
                        "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
                        "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "areaDes": "LF DR LF Door",
                        "type": "Prev Repair",
                        "desc": "Acceptable",
                        "estimate": "$ 0.00",
                        "isClickable": true,
                        "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
                        "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
                        "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "areaDes": "L FEND LF Fender",
                        "type": "Prev Repair",
                        "desc": "Buffable",
                        "estimate": "$ 0.00",
                        "isClickable": true,
                        "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
                        "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
                        "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "areaDes": "REAR Rear Bumper Cover",
                        "type": "Chipped",
                        "desc": "2",
                        "estimate": "$ 0.00",
                        "isClickable": true,
                        "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
                        "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
                        "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "areaDes": "RF DR RF Door",
                        "type": "Chipped",
                        "desc": "3",
                        "estimate": "$ 0.00",
                        "isClickable": true,
                        "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
                        "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
                        "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "areaDes": "R QTR R Qtr Panel",
                        "type": "Prev Repair",
                        "desc": "Acceptable",
                        "estimate": "$ 0.00",
                        "isClickable": true,
                        "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
                        "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
                        "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "areaDes": "RR DR RR Door",
                        "type": "Chipped",
                        "desc": "3",
                        "estimate": "$ 0.00",
                        "isClickable": true,
                        "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
                        "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
                        "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
                    }
                ]           }       ],      "totalDamages": 10,         "totalCost": "$ 0.00"   } }
```

In the above json i need all `regularUrl`s in one array, how to do that using map in angular2/typescript/rxjs.

Currently i am using two for loops or I can use three .maps for to get the regularUrls in one array.

How to solve this by using rxjs or typescript in angular2

Any solutions will be help full, Thank you

Comment: kumar, please accept and upvote :)

Comment: Actually, you don't need rxjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like that

```
let regularUrls = []; 

damages.regions.filter(region => region.hasOwnProperty('damageDetails') && region.damageDetails.length).map(region => {
    regularUrls = regularUrls.concat(region.damageDetails.map(damage => damage.regularUrl));
});
```

the `regularUrls` array will have all the regular Urls.

Here is a fiddle to test it http://jsfiddle.net/IbraheemAlSaady/xtr81m74/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
 var data = {  "damages": {   "regions": [{
        "name": "External Damages",
        "totalEstimatedCost": "$ 0.00",
        "damageDetails": [{
         "areaDes": "FRONT Hood",
         "type": "Prev Repair",
         "desc": "Acceptable",
         "estimate": "$ 0.00",
         "isClickable": true,
         "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
         "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
         "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
        }]    },    {
        "name": "Other Damages",
        "totalEstimatedCost": "$ 0.00",
        "damageDetails": [{
          "areaDes": "FRONT Front Bumper Cover",
          "type": "Prev Repair",
          "desc": "Acceptable",
          "estimate": "$ 0.00",
          "isClickable": true,
          "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
          "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
          "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
         },
         {
          "areaDes": "INT OPT Gas",
          "type": "Empty",
          "desc": "Unacceptable",
          "estimate": "$ 0.00",
          "isClickable": true,
          "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
          "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
          "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
         },
         {
          "areaDes": "LF DR L \"A\" Pillar",
          "type": "Prev Repair (Structure)",
          "desc": "Substd Repair",
          "estimate": "$ 0.00",
          "isClickable": true,
          "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
          "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
          "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
         },
         {
          "areaDes": "LF DR LF Door",
          "type": "Prev Repair",
          "desc": "Acceptable",
          "estimate": "$ 0.00",
          "isClickable": true,
          "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
          "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
          "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
         },
         {
          "areaDes": "L FEND LF Fender",
          "type": "Prev Repair",
          "desc": "Buffable",
          "estimate": "$ 0.00",
          "isClickable": true,
          "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
          "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
          "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
         },
         {
          "areaDes": "REAR Rear Bumper Cover",
          "type": "Chipped",
          "desc": "2",
          "estimate": "$ 0.00",
          "isClickable": true,
          "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
          "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
          "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
         },
         {
          "areaDes": "RF DR RF Door",
          "type": "Chipped",
          "desc": "3",
          "estimate": "$ 0.00",
          "isClickable": true,
          "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
          "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
          "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
         },
         {
          "areaDes": "R QTR R Qtr Panel",
          "type": "Prev Repair",
          "desc": "Acceptable",
          "estimate": "$ 0.00",
          "isClickable": true,
          "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
          "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
          "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
         },
         {
          "areaDes": "RR DR RR Door",
          "type": "Chipped",
          "desc": "3",
          "estimate": "$ 0.00",
          "isClickable": true,
          "regularUrl": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original.jpg",
          "midSizedPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_lb.jpg",
          "thumbNailPath": "https://adesa.test2.kar-media.com/display.php?img=283509519_d_ee9339f0-d9d9-48cb-ab15-66831f95dcd7-Original_th.jpg"
         }
        ]    }   ],   "totalDamages": 10,   "totalCost": "$ 0.00"  } }
data.damages.regions.filter(item=>item.hasOwnProperty('damageDetails'))
                .map((item, i) => item.damageDetails.map((it,j)=> console.log(it.regularUrl)))
```